# My first chrome extension getting permission errors to publish the extension. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, permissions, background

I am getting rejected with the below comments:

'User Data Privacy'

Your product violates the 'Use of Permissions' section of the policy, which requires that you:

Request access to the narrowest permissions necessary to implement your product’s features or services.
If more than one permission could be used to implement a feature, you must request those with the least access to data or functionality.
Don't attempt to 'future proof' your product by requesting a permission that might benefit services or features that have not yet been implemented.

My Extensions Manifest's file:-

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "int23",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Project 23",

  "background":{
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  
  "content_scripts":[
    {
      "matches":[
        "https://lincolnfinancialgroup.service-now.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "icons":{
    "128": "icon128.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "16": "icon16.png"
    },

    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "clipboardWrite",
      "nativeMessaging",
      "https://lincolnfinancialgroup.service-now.com/*"
    ],

    "browser_action":{
      "default_icon": "icon16.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": "B2B - EDM Helper"
    }
}
```

Background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(receiver);

window.word = "";

function receiver (request, sender, sendResponse){
    console.log(request);
    window.word = request

}
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message = "run"){
        Run();
    }
    
    function Run() {

        if (document.readyState == "interactive" || document.readyState == "complete") {


            console.log("Its running in LFG SNOW")

            var theIframe = document.getElementById("gsft_main")

            var text = theIframe.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll(".question_textarea_input")[5].value

            // text = text.replace(/\s/g, '')
            // console.log(text)
            var content = text.split("\n");
            var filtered = content.filter(Boolean);
            // console.log(filtered)

            var contentnew = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++){
                if (filtered[i] !== ""){
                    contentnew.push(filtered[i].replace(/\s/g, ''));
                }
            };

            // console.log(contentnew)

        }


        function findingIndex(string){

            var dig = contentnew.map(v => v.toLowerCase());

            // console.log(dig)
            var b = dig.filter(s => s.includes(string.toLowerCase())).toString()

            // console.log(b)

            var index = dig.indexOf(b)

            return index
        }

        function findingArrayIndex(string){

            var dig = contentnew.map(v => v.toLowerCase());

            // console.log(dig)
            var b = dig.filter(s => s.includes(string.toLowerCase()))

            if (b.length == 1){
                var string1 = b[0].toString()
                var index1 = dig.indexOf(string1)
                var dir1 = contentnew[index1].toString().replace(/^.*\=(.*)$/ig, "$1").replace(",", "").replace(/\\/i, '_').replace(/\\/g, '/')
                return dir1
            } else if (b.length == 2){
                var string1 = b[0].toString()
                var string2 = b[1].toString()
                var index1 = dig.indexOf(string1)
                var index2 = dig.indexOf(string2)
                var dir1 = contentnew[index1].toString().replace(/^.*\=(.*)$/ig, "$1").replace(",", "").replace(/\\/i, '_').replace(/\\/g, '/')
                var dir2 = contentnew[index2].toString().replace(/^.*\=(.*)$/ig, "$1").replace(",", "").replace(/\\/i, '_').replace(/\\/g, '/')
                return [dir1, dir2]
            } else {
                var string1 = b[0].toString()
                var string2 = b[1].toString()
                var string3 = b[3].toString()
                var index1 = dig.indexOf(string1)
                var index2 = dig.indexOf(string2)
                var index3 = dig.indexOf(string3)
                var dir1 = contentnew[index1].toString().replace(/^.*\=(.*)$/ig, "$1").replace(",", "").replace(/\\/i, '_').replace(/\\/g, '/')
                var dir2 = contentnew[index2].toString().replace(/^.*\=(.*)$/ig, "$1").replace(",", "").replace(/\\/i, '_').replace(/\\/g, '/')
                var dir3 = contentnew[index3].toString().replace(/^.*\=(.*)$/ig, "$1").replace(",", "").replace(/\\/i, '_').replace(/\\/g, '/')
                return [dir1, dir2, dir3]
            }

        }


        // findingArrayIndex("dir");
        // a = a.replace(/SubMB=/ig, '');

        // var a = contentnew.filter(s => s.includes("ne1pastore01"))
        // console.log(dir1);
        // console.log(dir2);
        // console.log(dir3.toString().replace(/^.*\/(.*)$/ig, "$1").replace(",", ""));

        const RITM = {

            RequestType: contentnew[findingIndex("RequestType")].toString().replace(/^.*\=(.*)$/ig, "$1").replace(",", ""),
            MB: contentnew[findingIndex("MB/ID=")].toString().replace(/^.*\=(.*)$/ig, "$1").replace(",", ""),
            SubMB: contentnew[findingIndex("SubMB=")].toString().replace(/^.*\=(.*)$/ig, "$1").replace(",", ""),
            ReceivingPGP: contentnew[findingIndex("ReceivingPGP")].toString().replace(/^.*\?(.*)$/ig, "$1", '').replace(",", ""),
            SendingPGP: contentnew[findingIndex("SendingPGP")].toString().replace(/^.*\?(.*)$/ig, "$1", '').replace(",", ""),
            Protocol: contentnew[findingIndex("Protocol")].toString().replace(/^.*\=(.*)$/ig, "$1", '').replace(",", ""),
            Site: contentnew[findingIndex("Site")].toString().replace(/^.*\=(.*)$/ig, "$1", '').replace(",", ""),
            FileName: contentnew[findingIndex("Rename")].toString().replace(/^.*\=(.*)$/ig, "$1", '').replace(",", ""),
            DetailedEmail: contentnew[findingIndex("Detail")].toString().replace(/^.*\=(.*)$/ig, "$1", '').replace(",", ""),
            InternalContact: contentnew[findingIndex("Internal")].toString().replace(/^.*\=(.*)$/ig, "$1", '').replace(",", ""),
            Directory: findingArrayIndex("dir")
        }

        console.log(RITM)

        var tbl = document.createElement('table');
        function CreateTable(){
            // var dv = document.getElementById("copycontent")
            
            tbl.setAttribute("id", "table101")
            tbl.style.width = '100%';
            if(RITM.Directory.length == 2) {
                
                tr = document.createElement('tr');
                tr1 = document.createElement('tr');

                var td1 = document.createElement('td');
                var td2 = document.createElement('td');
                var td3 = document.createElement('td');
                var td4 = document.createElement('td');
                var td5 = document.createElement('td');
                var td6 = document.createElement('td');
                var td7 = document.createElement('td');
                var td8 = document.createElement('td');
                var td9 = document.createElement('td');
                var td10 = document.createElement('td');
                var td11 = document.createElement('td');
                var td12 = document.createElement('td');
                var td13 = document.createElement('td');
                var td14 = document.createElement('td');
                var td15 = document.createElement('td');
                var td16 = document.createElement('td');
                var td17 = document.createElement('td');
                var td18 = document.createElement('td');
                var td19 = document.createElement('td');
                var td20 = document.createElement('td');
                var td21 = document.createElement('td');
                var td22 = document.createElement('td');
                var td23 = document.createElement('td');

                td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(RITM.SubMB));
                if (RITM.ReceivingPGP == "n" || RITM.ReceivingPGP == "N"){
                    td5.appendChild(document.createTextNode("LFG_Generic_Static_Routing_1"));
                } else if (RITM.ReceivingPGP == "y" || RITM.ReceivingPGP == "Y"){
                    td5.appendChild(document.createTextNode("LFG_Generic_Static_Route_PGP_Decrypt_Any_1"));
                } else {
                    td5.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Validate"));
                }
                
                td6.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Consumer"));
                td7.appendChild(document.createTextNode(RITM.MB));
                td8.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Prod_EDM"));
                td9.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                td10.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                td11.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                td12.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                td13.appendChild(document.createTextNode("no"));
                td14.appendChild(document.createTextNode("no"));
                td15.appendChild(document.createTextNode("no"));
                td16.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                td17.appendChild(document.createTextNode("no"));
                td18.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                td19.appendChild(document.createTextNode(RITM.Directory[0]));
                td20.appendChild(document.createTextNode(RITM.FileName));
                td21.appendChild(document.createTextNode(RITM.DetailedEmail));
                td22.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                td23.appendChild(document.createTextNode(RITM.InternalContact));


                tr.appendChild(td1);
                tr.appendChild(td2);
                tr.appendChild(td3);
                tr.appendChild(td4);
                tr.appendChild(td5);
                tr.appendChild(td6);
                tr.appendChild(td7);
                tr.appendChild(td8);
                tr.appendChild(td9);
                tr.appendChild(td10);
                tr.appendChild(td11);
                tr.appendChild(td12);
                tr.appendChild(td13);
                tr.appendChild(td14);
                tr.appendChild(td15);
                tr.appendChild(td16);
                tr.appendChild(td17);
                tr.appendChild(td18);
                tr.appendChild(td19);
                tr.appendChild(td20);
                tr.appendChild(td21);
                tr.appendChild(td22);
                tr.appendChild(td23);

                var d1 = document.createElement('td');
                var d2 = document.createElement('td');
                var d3 = document.createElement('td');
                var d4 = document.createElement('td');
                var d5 = document.createElement('td');
                var d6 = document.createElement('td');
                var d7 = document.createElement('td');
                var d8 = document.createElement('td');
                var d9 = document.createElement('td');
                var d10 = document.createElement('td');
                var d11 = document.createElement('td');
                var d12 = document.createElement('td');
                var d13 = document.createElement('td');
                var d14 = document.createElement('td');
                var d15 = document.createElement('td');
                var d16 = document.createElement('td');
                var d17 = document.createElement('td');
                var d18 = document.createElement('td');
                var d19 = document.createElement('td');
                var d20 = document.createElement('td');
                var d21 = document.createElement('td');
                var d22 = document.createElement('td');
                var d23 = document.createElement('td');

                d1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                d2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                d3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                d4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(RITM.SubMB + "_1"));
                d5.appendChild(document.createTextNode("LFG_Generic_Static_Routing_Secondary_MBX_1"));
                d6.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Consumer"));
                d7.appendChild(document.createTextNode(RITM.SubMB));
                d8.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Prod_EDM"));
                d9.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                d10.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                d11.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                d12.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                d13.appendChild(document.createTextNode("no"));
                d14.appendChild(document.createTextNode("no"));
                d15.appendChild(document.createTextNode("no"));
                d16.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                d17.appendChild(document.createTextNode("no"));
                d18.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                d19.appendChild(document.createTextNode(RITM.Directory[1]));
                if (RITM.FileName == "-CMB-.-OF1-_-DT2-.-OF2--XPG-"){
                    d20.appendChild(document.createTextNode("-PMB-.-OF1-_-DT2-.-OF2--XPG-"));
                } else {
                    d20.appendChild(document.createTextNode(RITM.FileName)); 
                }
                d21.appendChild(document.createTextNode(RITM.DetailedEmail));
                d22.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                d23.appendChild(document.createTextNode(RITM.InternalContact));

                tr1.appendChild(d1);
                tr1.appendChild(d2);
                tr1.appendChild(d3);
                tr1.appendChild(d4);
                tr1.appendChild(d5);
                tr1.appendChild(d6);
                tr1.appendChild(d7);
                tr1.appendChild(d8);
                tr1.appendChild(d9);
                tr1.appendChild(d10);
                tr1.appendChild(d11);
                tr1.appendChild(d12);
                tr1.appendChild(d13);
                tr1.appendChild(d14);
                tr1.appendChild(d15);
                tr1.appendChild(d16);
                tr1.appendChild(d17);
                tr1.appendChild(d18);
                tr1.appendChild(d19);
                tr1.appendChild(d20);
                tr1.appendChild(d21);
                tr1.appendChild(d22);
                tr1.appendChild(d23);


                tbl.appendChild(tr);
                tbl.appendChild(tr1);

                chrome.runtime.sendMessage(tbl.innerHTML);

            }
            console.log(tbl)

        }
        
        CreateTable();

    }
});
```

popup.js

```
console.log("Hello World")

var button = document.querySelector("#copy");
var button2 = document.querySelector("#copy_btn");

button2.addEventListener('click', function(){

    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message: "run"});
    });

})

button.addEventListener('click', function(){

    let bgpage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    let word = bgpage.word;
    
    console.log(word)

    var paragraph = document.createElement("table");
    // paragraph.style.visibility = "hidden";
    paragraph.id = "tablecreated"
    // paragraph.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true")
    paragraph.className = "offscreen"
    paragraph.innerHTML = word;
    console.log(paragraph)

    document.body.appendChild(paragraph)
    // paragraph.style.visibility = "hidden";
    

    var val = document.querySelector('#tablecreated');
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(val);  
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('copy');

}, false);
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>parseInt('23')</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        /* table, tr, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        } */
        html body {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 348 px;
            min-height: 180px;
        }
        .offscreen {
            position: absolute;
            left: -999em;
        }

        img {
            width: 80px;

        }

        h1 {
            align-items: center;
            font-family: 'Menlo', monospace;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 200;
            margin: 0;
            color: #2f5876;

        }

        /* .modal-header{
            align-items: center;
            border-bottom: 0.5px solid #dadada;
        } */

        .modal-content {
            padding-top: 12px;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .version{
            color: #444;
            font-size: 11px;
        }
        .flex-container{
            display:flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 10px 22px;
            padding-right: 12px;
        }
        .flex{
            opacity: 1;
            transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
            width: 120px;
            align-items: center;
            padding-right: 25px;
        }

        .flex:hover{
            align-items: center;
            opacity: 0.4;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="logo">
            <img src="unnamed.png" alt="parseInt('23')" class="logo-icon">
            new String(23)<span class="version">v0.23</span>  
        </h1>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="modal-content">
        <p>Your B2B friendly extension!</p> -->
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex">
        
            <button type="button" id="copy_btn" class="btn btn-success">Forge it!</button>
  
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
            <button type="button" id="copy" class="btn btn-success">Replicate</button>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <button type="button" id="btn">Click It!</button> -->
    <!-- <button type="button" id="copy_btn">Copy Table</button> -->
    
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any suggestions on which permissions I am missing out or needs to be removed?

Sorry I am kind of new to the programming world too!(Javascript). My codes might not have a structure apologize for it. Not a great code but it does the job which I wanted to achieve. Still a learner, also open to any corrections on my code. Thank you all for the help!

This is my question post to stack overflow (first stepping stone to become a developer).

Comment: Remove all the permissions you're not using i.e. `nativeMessaging` and `https://lincolnfinancialgroup.service-now.com/*`, as well as `clipboardWrite` which is optional even though the documentation recommends it.

Comment: I have removed all of them and kept only tabs permission since I am using it in popup.js but still I am getting rejected with permission issue. Do I need to remove tabs permission as well or is it something I need to alter in script?

Comment: Ah, try replacing `tabs` with `activeTab` in manifest. Your code should be able to work as is.

Comment: I removed all the permissions mentioned and submitted eventually it got published. Thanks for the help @wOxxOm